# Oracle procedure inside a trgigger to check the output

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, triggers, database

I am trying to call my procedure inside a trigger. 
The trigger is created successfully but the procedure is calling being called.

I am using oracle 10g with SQL developer tool. 
I have tried to see the dbms_output but nothing shows in DBMS_OUTPUT console except"set serveroutput on" when i update the table.

My trigger is

```
create or replace
TRIGGER trig_sample
AFTER UPDATE
ON sample_table
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN


SAMPLE_PROC(:NEW.PARAM1, :NEW.PARAM2 ,:NEW.PRAMA3);

END;
```

procedure is

```
CREATE or REPLACE Procedure SAMPLE_PROC(PARAM1 NUMBER,PARAM2 NUMBER,PARAM3 varchar2)


 BEGIN 

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('test : '||test); 

UPDATE SAMPLE_TABLE SET STATUS = 'VA'
    WHERE SAMPLE_ID = '2012'; 

END;
```

In my procedure i have used DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('test : '||test);
but could not see any output. Please provide any suggestions to view the DBMS output in console and how to check the trigger is called or not?

Comment: Can you post the procedure as well please?

Comment: To check the trigger, place another dbms_output just after begin inside the trigger.

Comment: With the above code, when you run you will get `ORA-04091: table SAMPLE_TABLE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` error.